# How to make streaming video player?

Tags: java, android

I need to make Android streaming video player which can play video from my embedded system.

But I have a few questions:

1. How can embedded web-sever send notification to the android device , without knowing the device's ip address.
2. How does the embedded web-sever know a device ip address without the device first connecting to the embedded webserver? Is the device address static?
3. And last - Is there internal Android application for playing streaming video?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the other way around. Your streaming server sits at a certain url, so your Android client can connect to this url. 
For example many cameras send their rtsp data on port 554 while they can be queried and controlled by sending/receiving commands on port 80 of the same URL.

You can try to use Android MediaPlayer class to play your stream. However its capabilities are rather limited, maybe it won't be able to play your stream. In this case they use FFMPEG libraries or other such libraries to receive and decode streams. These are not trivial.